# How can I add those white lines inside the letters

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, typography

I am just wondering how I can add those white, light reflection kind of lines inside the Font just how it is in the Nesquik logo in Photoshop CC

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Typically this is done in a *vector* drawing application and the inner highlights are added *manually*:

[image]

It's also possible in Adobe Illustrator, to use multiple fills and a clipping mask....

[image]

<sub>The base shape (N) is used as a clipping mask on the existing N with multiple fills.</sub>

If I were *forced* to use Photoshop and could *not* use the Pen Tool to draw the highlights manually, then I'd use selections of the base shape and a mask on a separate highlight layer.

[image]

Drawing the highlights with the Pen Tool in photoshop would provide more control overall, and really that's the method I'd suggest.

You could also spend an inordinate amount of time trying to figure out what exact Bevel & Emboss settings, along with the Contour may result in a properly positioned highlight. That's more a trial and error exploration.

Answer (score 1):

In photoshop you can use layer effects to get a similar look.
Type your text

1. Add layer effect ”Bevel and Emboss”: Style =  emboss, Technique =
   smooth, Depth = 200%, Direction = Up, Size = 4px (change to fit your
   image), Soften = 0px. Set light angle to 120 and altitude to 25-30,
   Highlight opacity to 100% and Shadow to 15%.
2. Add Layer effect “Stroke”: Size = 4px (change to fit your image),
   Position = Outside and Color = Same color as your text color.
3. Add another Layer effect “Stroke”: Size = 10px (change to fit your
   image), Position = Outside and Color = white
4. With the text layer active click the Layer meny up in the right
   corner of the Layer tab and choose “New group from layer” (ctrl+G)
5. Now you can add a yellow shadow layer effect to the group, Tweak the
   settings to fit your image.
   [image]